# How can I further identify a file which the file command lists as 'data'

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format, digital-forensics

I have file named 'out'. If I issue the file command I see :

```
:~/Desktop# file out
out: data
```

How can I further identify what type of file this is? Interestingly, if I execute the file, I see a 'syntax error near unexpected token' error, suggesting it might be an executable, rather than data. Above command issued on linux.

The file in question was outputted by `outguess` and is part of a steganography puzzle

Comment: Did you try running a "strings" or "binwalk" on it?

Comment: strings does find some strings in the file. Binwalk I am not familiar with. I tried binwalk -A (empty output). If you can suggest some things to try I can add them to the question maybe?

Comment: Are you convinced it should be a common file type, or could it be some private data format? Not all files in the world are of common types.

Comment: it is part of a steganography challenge. I was expecting the file to contain hashes. But that was just a guess really. It would not necessarily be a common file type and could be encrypted in some way.

Comment: Blind guess, could it be XOR? In that case I would try [this tool](https://github.com/hellman/xortool). If it's really stego then you pretty much left with doing statistical analysis and try figuring out some kind of structure of your file. Maybe they used one of the softwares listed [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/steganography-and-tools-to-perform-steganography/)?

Comment: Most RE tools only exist for automating slow brainless tasks. Open the file in a hex editor and read it. I bet that was the whole point of a challenge - to  force people to think, make hypotheses and then prove/disprove them.

Comment: As suggested by Vitaly open the file with a hex editor try to identify header and trailer. Maybe its crypted ? try to past here hex of the file.

Comment: @SoufianeTahiri unfortunately the Hex is too long to paste here. Character limit is 30000

Comment: Did you try winhex ?